# Show a div only when a button clicked

Tags: jquery, html, show

How can I show a div on a button click, and hide it otherwise?

I have already the button for show:

```
<script>
 $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#content").show();
    });
});
</script>

<div class="content">Content of div</p>

<button id="show">show</button>
```

Comment: you div has class content while you are using id selector, and your current script has syntax error, there are extra parenthesis at end

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use a `toogle()` instead of `show()` and `hide()`.

And also to put your code in the `ready()`.

If you don't want to show it from the start, use the `display : none` or `visibility: hidden;` property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style = "display: none;">This is a div.</div>

<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! But the div should just be visible when a button was clicked. Not directly at the join of the page.

Comment: I think i need a js event for the invoke of my page.

Comment: @Tim I don't think that is required, a small `CSS` tweak is more than enough

Answer (score 0):

You can add visibility  property for a div  like visibility : "hidden"

Comment: but the div does not should be visible. Only then the button clicked.